# send data with categories from client to a server using python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, embedded

I have an embedded system that monitors many sensors (GPS, Motor Speed, Temperature..)

I set up a client-server using sockets in python and I can send from the client(the embedded system) to the server(a Laptop) a string message like " Hello from client ".

But for me it would be great to send data with predifined categories so the server knows the type of the message. Upon reception the server knows it has recieved for example a GPS coordinate or motor speed.

Is there a way to do it in TCP or using any library or framework?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, the category has to be part of the data. Everything you want to send, it all has to be part of the data.

Comment: There are countless ways to do this over TCP. You could set up a regular old web server--sending structured data over TCP is what HTTP _is_, If your embedded system can make http requests, that might be simplest. You could use Protocol Buffers, or you could define your own data transport protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three ways

1. Put the message kind in the header (next to the message size, probably)
2. Use different sockets for each message kind (ugly and complicated but works)
3. Use some sort of pub-sub e.g. Kafka, ZeroMQ or RabbitMQ to convey topics